# How can I remove proxies from entity

Tags: entity-framework, session, proxy

I need to store User settings (like address,accessright etc..) in session/cache in order to access them via basecontroller(MVC project).

When I try to reach `User.Address` from session as can be imagine it says:

> The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used
>   for operations that require a connection.

Address is a Navigational property on User entity.

I don't wanna use DTO.

Are there any workaround for that?

thanks.

Comment: Address is a sort of lazzy load property? you should load all of them if session context will lost dbContext.

Comment: Yes, Address is a lazy load property.

Comment: What is the connection between the title and the question? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm agree with Gert but I prefer to write like this. (for Compile time error checking)

```
public User GetUser(int userId)
{
    using (var db = new MyContext())
    {
        return db.Users.Include( p => p.Address).Single(u => u == userId);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you fetch the user from the database you must `Include` the address. For instance, something like this (in a repository or service):

```
public User GetUser(int userId)
{
    using (var db = new MyContext())
    {
        return db.Users.Include("Address").Single(u => u == userId);
    }
}
```